# ubuntu unicorn unfinished install hickup

Tags: boot

i installed newest ubuntu 14.10 unicorn on my brand new ssd pc , but think i made an mistake. When files had finished installing the boot media  - a dvd i burned - where pushed out.. i removed the cd.. and my pc just hang there not booting properly up.. guess i should have let it stay in the dvd and finished the installation before removing it.
I have access to recovery-mode 3.16.0-24-generic.. but the option it gives me haven’t been able to solve the boot problem up till now.
Any suggestion would be much appreciated.. im a linux noob so please be gentle ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to just install again. If you see a reason not to do so, state it.

Comment: im aware of that.. but i only get 3 option in the recovery menu, namely 1. Start Ubuntu as normal. (Just hangs there in the booting process ) 2. Enter Advanced Settings. Now allows me to Enter normal boot procedure, which works, but is a temporary solution. 3. Enter System Settings ( which bring me to MSI bios with its options for letting me manipulate system coolers etc )... How do I force the pc to start up all from the beginning and re-install anew ?

Comment: Put installation medium in, reboot, hold F8 while rebooting, choose that medium from the list. Prefer `UEFI` version if present.

Comment: i did as suggested - except on my pc is it the "DEL"-key.. and indeed entered re-install.. chose UEFI.. left the medium in the dvd player after inital setup of ubuntu, and rebooted with ubuntu cd still in.. unfortunately with the same hang-up problem as before.. Still open for suggestions, but call it a day for now.. sleep awaits before work calls in the morning .. will be back later after work.

Comment: forget to mention that i chose to encrypt my home map.. if that helps..

Comment: New day, new attempt: Installed Ubuntu 14.10 without encrypting home directory.. this funny enough made my system being able to boot to a full desktop.. no UEFI as recommended though as system says "booting in insecure mode". Would like UEFI to work but a quick glance around this sites show people with MSi motherboards having trouble booting at all if UEFI is forced..

Comment: I print out a bit of my hardware with lshw, and it goes like this: *-core
       description: Motherboard
       physical id: 0
     *-memory
          description: System memory
          physical id: 0
          size: 3881MiB
     *-cpu
          product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-4150 CPU @ 3.50GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 1
          bus info: cpu@0
          width: 64 bits